# How can I make someone review my code on GitLab and not give them permission to clone it?

Tags: git, gitlab, git-branch, git-clone, cloneable

My manager asked me to add a person to my GitLab repo to review it but this person should not be able to to clone it.

Also, can I add a person but so they can see only the branches that I want them to see and not all branches?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you should clone the repo yourself and remove all other branches before sharing.

Comment: The corporate solution : download the repo, remove `.git`, create `.zip` and send via email.

Comment: But what if I want him to review without having the code, I thought that I can do a share screen with the reviewer can you suggest another solution for me?

Comment: If someone can *see* the code, they can *copy* the code: if all else fails they can take a screenshot and run that through a text recognition algorithm, or even transcribe it manually. So your goal is literally impossible. You'll have to scale it down to something that's possible, e.g., to send that person just the bits you want that person to be able to see.